# In SQL how do I find the first record per-user if it's within a time slice, without scanning the entire DB

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a database, `user_requests` that basically looks like this:

```
  user_id  |    request_timestamp    | request_type | other_metadata
-----------|-------------------------|--------------|----------------
  user1    |    2018-11-01:04:04:41  |    type1     | opaquedata_A
  user2    |    2018-11-01:04:03:41  |    type2     | opaquedata_B
  user1    |    2018-11-01:04:01:41  |    type1     | opaquedata_C
  user3    |    2018-11-01:04:05:41  |    type3     | opaquedata_D
  user4    |    2018-11-01:04:01:41  |    type4     | opaquedata_E
```

And it is *huge*. Doing any operation over the entire thing is absolutely untenable, everything needs to be like "which queries were most common **this month**" no one ever checks it overall.

What I'm trying to do is some analysis on the first requests for several user. I absolutely do not need the first requests of *every* user or over all-time, as long as it's a representative sample.

However I'm running into a problem where all my usual attempts to restrict this are finding "the first request within bounds" not "the first request *if it's within bounds*"

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,
              first_value(request_type) over (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY request_timestamp
                rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following) requestType,
              first_value(other_metadata) over (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY request_timestamp
                rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following) otherMetadata,
              first_value(request_timestamp) over (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY request_timestamp
                rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding and unbounded following) utteranceTimestamp
FROM user_requests
WHERE request_timestamp BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND request_timestamp < '2018-12-01'
```

Like this finds the earliest request from a user in November, when what I want is the earliest request from a user *overall* if that request is in November.

Any idea how I can get what I want while still writing queries that don't take hours to complete?

Comment: Start with the earliest partition and see who started then.  I might recommend that you maintain a summary table of the earliest request, and that this be included as part of the data load process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a tweaked form of an alternate [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query:

```
SELECT Curr.user_id, Curr.request_type, Curr.other_metadata, Curr.request_timestamp
FROM User_Requests Curr
WHERE  Curr.request_timestamp >='2018-11-01' 
       AND Curr.request_timestamp < '2018-12-01'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM User_Requests Prev
                       WHERE Prev.user_id = Curr.user_id
                             AND Prev.request_timestamp < Curr.request_timestamp)
```

...This finds all requests within the given time frame, and then throws out any if there is **ANY** earlier request - during the month or otherwise.  This not only gets the earliest-in-month, but also has the effect of ignoring requests in the desired timeframe if there are other previous queries too.

For best results, you'll need an index on `(user_id, request_timestamp)`.
(Note that I'm assuming that the optimizer is being nice and translating your dates into the proper types for a ranged search.  You might want to verify that `request_timestamp` isn't being cast.)

---

Bonus `LEFT JOIN`-exclusion form in case it performs better.

```
SELECT Curr.user_id, Curr.request_type, Curr.other_metadata, Curr.request_timestamp
FROM User_Requests Curr
LEFT JOIN User_Requests Prev
       ON Prev.user_id = Curr.user_id
          AND Prev.request_timestamp < Curr.request_timestamp
WHERE  Curr.request_timestamp >='2018-11-01' 
       AND Curr.request_timestamp < '2018-12-01'
       AND Prev.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: First one worked, second query fails, "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table user_requests"

Comment: @StolenKitten - oops, looks like I forgot to change a table reference name.  Updated.